# how to parse csv with name value pairs as text cells with colon seperation

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

believe it or not, i couldn't find anywhere an answer to this:
i have csv files with the following format:

```
Epoch: 1 Loss: 164.0284653747 
Epoch: 2 Loss: 164.0155072829
Epoch: 3 Loss: 163.9634398650 
Epoch: 4 Loss: 163.8925548714 
Epoch: 5 Loss: 163.9922899258
```

how can i use pandas.read_csv to parse correctly and get out a dataframe:

epoch -------   Loss

1  -------------164.0284653747

2  -------------164.0155072829

hope my illustration is clear enough, i just want a dataframe with 2 columns named epoch and loss and the corresponding values.

Comment: Just FYI, CSV stands for comma-separated values file. While `pandas` will read it in as a CSV file, most of its functionality will not be particularly useful unless you change the delimiter from a comma to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, you can read your file in with pandas and manually clean it up.

you could write a regex parses but the engine will change from `c` to `python` meaning you will lose the speed of the underlying cython code.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=':',header=None)

df[1] = df[1].replace('\D+','',regex=True).astype(int)

df = df[[1,2]].rename(columns={1 : 'Epoch', 2 : 'Loss'})

print(df)

  Epoch        Loss
0      1  164.028465
1      2  164.015507
2      3  163.963440
3      4  163.892555
4      5  163.992290
```

Comment: this solves the problem, i guess i thought there's some way to do it with one line of code in the read_csv function

Comment: @enter_thevoid it's possible, but you lose readability which is better imo. `pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=':',header=None,usecols=[1,2]).replace('\D+','',regex=True).rename(columns={1 : 'Epoch', 2 : 'Loss'})`

Answer (score 1):

CSV stands for comma-separated values file. While pandas will read it in as a CSV file, most of its functionality will not be particularly useful unless you change the delimiter from a comma to something else. Also, the data is not in a traditional table, which is again what CSV is defined for.

All that said, however, there is a "hackish" way of treating your input as a CSV:

```
csv_file = "something.csv"
df = pandas.read_csv(
    csv_file,
    header=None,
    sep=" ",
    names=[1, "Epoch", 3, "Loss"],
    index_col=False
)[["Epoch", "Loss"]]
```

Basically, you are setting the delimiter to a space `" "`, defining all the columns with names and only selecting the second and fourth columns named `Epoch` and `Loss`

Comment: you could add `use_cols=[1,3]1 to save the end column slice, i like this answer but i feel splititng by white space is to risky, even with structured data, there are always those little bug bears that will come and bite you in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
di_2 = []
di_1 = []
with open("passenger_1.csv", "r") as p:
   file = csv.reader(p)
   for i in file:
       di_1.append(i[0].split(" ")[1])
       di_2.append(i[0].split(" ")[3])
df = pd.DataFrame({
"Epoch": di_1,
"Loss": di_2
  })
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: I'm just reorganizing the CSV file first, read the file line by line, and then split every line expression into the list.
second, create tow empty list which will carry the "Epoch" and the "Loss"
Finally, create a DataFrame.